# Rails 5.2 - cache is not being updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, redis, ruby-on-rails-5

I have this scheme in my views:

**_user_data.html.erb**:

```
<tbody>
  <%= render partial: 'edit_history_inline_user', collection: @presenter.collection, as: :user, cached: Proc.new{|user| [acl_fingerprint, 'history', user.record] } %>
</tbody>
```

**_edit_history_inline_user.html.erb**:

```
<td class="align_center">
  <%= user.first_name %>
</td>
<td class="align_center">
  <%= user.last_name %>
</td>
...
```

The problem is that when I update the `user` model, the data in the **_edit_history_inline_user.html.erb** are not being updated. If I make some change, though, in the **_edit_history_inline_user.html.erb** file, such as (adding the `--` characters):

```
<td class="align_center">
  -- <%= user.first_name %> --
</td>
```

The correct/recently modified data will be displayed. How is that possible? Why the modified data does not show up correctly?

Here's the `acl_fingerprint` method that I use in the parent partial view:

```
def acl_fingerprint
  Rails.cache.fetch("#{current_admin.cache_key(:current_sign_in_at, :updated_at)}/acl_fingerprint", expires_in: 3.hours) do
    CacheService.acl_fingerprint(current_admin, params[:controller])
  end
end
```

How do I fix this issue?

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, `acl_fingerprint` will not change when you update user (unless you update `current_admin`, in that case cache should expire). So that leaves `'history'` string which will never change, and `user.record`.

The easy solution would be to include user's `updated_at` to to the cache key (you could use `user.cache_key_with_version`).

The reason why your cache expire once you modify template is because Rails include template checksum in the cache key.

Comment: Hi @RolandasBarysas, thanks for your answer. The problem was that I was updating the model with the `.update_all` method, which doesn't timestamp the `updated_at` field. Because the query I have there is quite complex, I solved the situation by simply adding `updated_at: DateTime.now` to the `.update_all` method.